# Prove that if $\binom{p}{k} \mod p=0 $ for $k=1,2,..,p−1$ then $p$ is prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

Is the statement true? if it is, how to prove it?

If $\binom{p}{k} \mod p=0 $ for $k=1,2,..,p−1$ then $p$ is prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $N = ab$ is composite with positive integers $a,b > 1$ and $a$ is the smallest prime factor of $N$. Then $$\binom{N}{a} = \binom{ab}{a} = \dfrac{ab(ab-1) \cdots (ab-(a-1))}{a!} = \dfrac{b(ab-1) \cdots (ab-(a-1))}{(a-1)!}.$$ Then $(ab-1)(ab-2) \cdots (ab-(a-1)) \equiv \pm (a-1)!\pmod{ab}$. Thus, $\binom{ab}{a} \equiv b \pmod{ab}$.

Comment: Very elegant! +1

Comment: How come $(ab−1)(ab−2)⋯(ab−(a−1))≡±(a−1)!(\mod ab)$/

Comment: @JC Multiply out the brackets. All terms except the last have a factor of $ab$, so the whole product is congruent to the last term, which is $(-1)^{a-1}(a-1)!$.

Comment: And I think you want a $\pm$ in that last expression in the answer, @user19405892.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.$${p \choose k} = \frac{p \cdot (p-1) \cdot (p-2) \cdots (p-k+1)}{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdots k}$$